# Limit concurrent method executions inside call()

Tags: multithreading, callable

I have a call() method in my code, which based on certain conditions calls specific methods :

```
call(){
  if(a){
      methodA(); 
  }
  if(b){
      methodB(); 
  }
  if(c){
      methodC(); 
  }
}
```

In the above scenario, I want to limit concurrent executions for methodC.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "limit" ?

Comment: Suppose multiple threads (eg. 10 threads) are calling call() method and for all threads if(c) returns true, then at a time only specific number of threads (eg. 3) should execute methodC concurrently. Others will execute after these 3 threads have finished their task. Hence, limiting the concurrent executions of methodC to 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is a [Semaphore](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Semaphore) construct (check the bouncer/night club specification in the example).

```
// Create the semaphore with 3 slots, where 3 are available.
var bouncer = new Semaphore(3, 3);

call(){
  if(a){
      methodA(); 
  }
  if(b){
      methodB(); 
  }
  if(c){
      // Let a thread execute only after acquiring access (a semaphore to be released).
      Bouncer.WaitOne(); 
      methodC(); 
      // This thread is done. Let someone else go for it 
      Bouncer.Release(1); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the number of concurrent executions to at most one at a time, then you should use a `Lock`. In Java it should look like:

```
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
call() {
  if(a) {
      methodA(); 
  }
  if(b) {
      methodB(); 
  }
  if(c) {
      lock.lock();
      try {
         methodC(); 
      } finally {
         lock.unlock();
      }
  }
}
```

If you want to limit the number of concurrent executions to more than one at a time, you can use a `Semaphore`; here CONCURRENT_CALLS_ALLOWED is an int.

```
final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(CONCURRENT_CALLS_ALLOWED);
call() {
  if(a) {
      methodA(); 
  }
  if(b) {
      methodB(); 
  }
  if(c) {
      semaphore.aquire();//throws checked exception
      try {
         methodC(); 
      } finally {
         semaphore.release();
      }
  }
}
```